# How to suspend my app on fixed page, when there is not network?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to stop my app from working (showing fixed page, "there is not connection") if there is no internet connection, and it will continuously check internet connect.

Comment: There is the pub.dartlang.org/packages/connectivity plugin to check if the network is connected. You can repeatedly try to reach a server in the internet to check if the network is connected to the internet.

Comment: In addition , i think you can route a page and use WillPopScope, cancel pop if connection not exist.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use this packages

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_offline

Screenshot

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can user following plugin to listen to internet connectivity:

https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity#-readme-tab-

But I use following:

```
_checkInternetConnection() {
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      _splashFunction();
    });
  }

_splashFunction() async {
AppUtil.checkInternetConnectivity().then((isOnline) async {
if (isOnline) {...}else{_checkInternetConnection()}})}


static Future<bool> checkInternetConnectivity() async {
    bool isConnected;
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        isConnected = true;
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      isConnected = false;
    }
    return isConnected;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) package with the `StreamBuilder`

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    // Initially snapshot might be null, so use this to avoid errors
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    } else {
      ConnectivityResult result = snapshot.data;

      // Check Connectivity result here and display your widgets
      if(ConnectivityResult.none) {
        yourWidgetForNoInternet();
      } else {
        yourWidgetForInternet();
      }
    }
  },
)
```